# null reference exception stack

Tags: asp.net

Can any one explain this exception?

Server Error in '/eims_web' Application:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Description:

```
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +24
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.PopulateXmlDocument(XmlDocument document, CacheDependency& dataCacheDependency, CacheDependency& transformCacheDependency) +342
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument() +253
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlHierarchicalDataSourceView.Select() +51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindItem(MenuItem item) +326
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.PerformDataBinding() +99
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +126
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBind() +29
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +104
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.EnsureDataBound() +70
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +43
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e, Boolean registerScript) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +63
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +322
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +322
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +322
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4837
```

Comment: It looks like your XmlDocument failed to load.  Make sure your xml declaration is correct and there are no errors in the xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it is going to be hard to say, but by the looks of the stack trace, I will wager a guess and say you have a TreeView/Menu bound to an `XmlDataSource`.

Clearly something is going wrong during the databinding process, but again without seeing your code that populates the `XmlDataSource` it is going to be next to impossible to assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlReader` instance passed from `XmlDocument.Load` to `XmlLoader.Load` is null, which means that `XmlDataSource.PopulateXmlDocument` passes a null reader to `XmlDocument.Load`, which occurs when `XmlDataSource.GetReader` returns null.

The only code path where this happens requires that `XmlDataSource.DataFile` is null or empty *and* `XmlDataSource.Data` is either null, empty or costs of only white-space characters.